# Vitest test doesn't work with PrimeVue3 Dialogs

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite, vitest, primevue

I've got a project where I use PrimeVue components and it's time to do some tests.

This is the code of the test:

```
import { beforeEach, describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import type { VueWrapper } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Dialog from 'primevue/dialog'
import MyDialog from '@/components/modal/MyDialog.vue'
// Other imports...



describe('MyDialog', () => {
  let myDialogWrapper: VueWrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    myDialogWrapper= shallowMount(MyDialog , {
      props: {
        visible: false
      },
      global: {
        stubs: {
          // Some elements
        },
      }
    })
  })

  it('mount', () => {
    expect(myDialogWrapper).toBeTruthy()
    expect(myDialogWrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot()
    **console.log(myDialogWrapper.html())**
  })
})
```

But that console log does not print the component. It prints the following:

`<portal-stub data-v-eb267b8d="" appendto="body" disabled="false"></portal-stub>`

If I want to test, for example, that the "Close button" works, I'm trying to see if the button is displayed, so I should do something like this:

```
it('displays close button', async () => {
   myDialogWrapper.setProps({ visible: true })
   await myDialogWrapper.vm.$nextTick()
   const button = myDialogWrapper.find('.p-button-secondary')
   expect(button.exists()).toBe(true)
})
```

But, MyDialog.find does not find the button, so I can't handle the .trigger('click') event.

Instead of **ShallowMount** i've tried using **Mount** but, although the print is different, it's still not the fullth component.

I've also tried `.findComponent(Button)` instead of `.find('.p-button-secondary')` but it doesn't work either.

It only happens with Dialog tests and I've find that more people is struggling with this, but no one gives a solution that I can apply.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Dialog gets teleported, it has some special behavior.
With this [Stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74015665/vitest-wrapper-doesnt-show-teleported-html) and this [vue test utils docs](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/teleport.html), I found out that the html you are looking for is not inside the component (only in the Virtual Dom, which is not used somehow?).

**My Solution:** 
Inside the MyDialog.vue you could add `append-to="self"` to the `<Dialog>` so it does get teleported to the correct location in the DOM.

I do not know how your MyDialog.vue looks, but mine only contains a single `<Dialog>`, with everything i want to test inside the Dialog-Tag, so i need to do a `mount` instead of a `shallowMount`. Otherwise you only get the Stub in your `wrapper.html()`.

I hope this helps, it worked for me but i get a `dialog-stub` instead of your `portal-stub`. If it does not help, providing your MyDialog.vue could help me analyze your issue furter.

Answer (score 1):

A answer that doesn't require eliminating teleports in the production app itself is to stub out teleports by passing teleport: true in the global stubs option.

```
myDialogWrapper= shallowMount(MyDialog , {
        props: {
          visible: false
        },
        global: {
          stubs: {
            teleport: true
            // Some elements
          },
        }
      })
```

For other alternatives see the [Testing Teleport](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/teleport.html) documentation for vitest.

As for reasons why Teleport in the production app is valuable see: https://enterprisevue.dev/blog/understanding-vue-teleport/
(the reason there I would say is key is the [Accessibility and Modularity](https://enterprisevue.dev/blog/understanding-vue-teleport/#accessibility-and-modularity) section as that is the harder use-case to ensure compatibility with via other means).